# Dividing each cell in a data set by the column sum in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to divide each cell in a data frame by the sum of the column. For example, I have a data frame df:

```
sample   a   b   c
a2      1    4    6
a3      5    5    4
```

I would like to create a new data frame that takes each cell in and divides by the sum of the column, like so:

```
sample   a   b   c
a2      .167  .444  .6
a3      .833  .556  .4
```

I have seen answers using sweep(), but that looks like its for matrices, and I have data frames. I understand how to use colSums(), but I'm not sure how to write a function that loops through every cell in the column, and then divides by the column sum. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `d[-1] <- prop.table(as.matrix(d[-1]), margin = 2)`

Comment: @Henrik what does `prop.table()`? it seams that it is not the requested output...

Comment: Related post for matrix: [Dividing columns by colSums in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447801/dividing-columns-by-colsums-in-r)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given this:

```
> d = data.frame(sample=c("a2","a3"),a=c(1,5),b=c(4,5),c=c(6,4))
> d
  sample a b c
1     a2 1 4 6
2     a3 5 5 4
```

You can replace every column other than the first by applying over the rest:

```
> d[,-1] = apply(d[,-1],2,function(x){x/sum(x)})

> d
  sample         a         b   c
1     a2 0.1666667 0.4444444 0.6
2     a3 0.8333333 0.5555556 0.4
```

If you don't want `d` being stomped on make a copy beforehand.

Answer (score 20):

#### Solution 1

Here are two [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) solutions. We can use `mutate_at` or `mutate_if` to efficiently specify which column we want to apply an operation, or under what condition we want to apply an operation.

```
library(dplyr)

# Apply the operation to all column except sample
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-sample), funs(./sum(.))) 
dat2
#   sample         a         b   c
# 1     a2 0.1666667 0.4444444 0.6
# 2     a3 0.8333333 0.5555556 0.4

# Apply the operation if the column is numeric 
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(./sum(.))) 
dat2
#   sample         a         b   c
# 1     a2 0.1666667 0.4444444 0.6
# 2     a3 0.8333333 0.5555556 0.4
```

#### Solution 2

We can also use the `map_at` and `map_if` function from the [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) package. However, since the output is a list, we will need `as.data.frame` from base R or `as_data_frame` from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) to convert the list to a data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Apply the operation to column a, b, and c    
dat2 <- dat %>%
  map_at(c("a", "b", "c"), ~./sum(.)) %>% 
  as_data_frame()
dat2
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   sample     a     b     c
#   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a2     0.167 0.444 0.600
# 2 a3     0.833 0.556 0.400

# Apply the operation if the column is numeric
dat2 <- dat %>%
  map_if(is.numeric, ~./sum(.)) %>%
  as_data_frame()
dat2
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   sample     a     b     c
#   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a2     0.167 0.444 0.600
# 2 a3     0.833 0.556 0.400
```

#### Solution 3

We can also use the `.SD` and `.SDcols` from the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package.

```
library(data.table)

# Convert to data.table
setDT(dat)
dat2 <- copy(dat)
dat2[, (c("a", "b", "c")) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/sum(x)), .SDcols = c("a", "b", "c")]
dat2[]
#    sample         a         b   c
# 1:     a2 0.1666667 0.4444444 0.6
# 2:     a3 0.8333333 0.5555556 0.4
```

#### Solution 4

We can also use the `lapply` function to loop through all column except the first column to perform the operation.

```
dat2 <- dat
dat2[, -1] <- lapply(dat2[, -1], function(x) x/sum(x))
dat2
#   sample         a         b   c
# 1     a2 0.1666667 0.4444444 0.6
# 2     a3 0.8333333 0.5555556 0.4
```

We can also use apply to loop through all columns but add an if-else statement in the function to make sure only perform the operation on the numeric columns.

```
dat2 <- dat
dat2[] <- lapply(dat2[], function(x){
  # Check if the column is numeric
  if (is.numeric(x)){
    return(x/sum(x))
  } else{
    return(x)
  }
})
dat2
#   sample         a         b   c
# 1     a2 0.1666667 0.4444444 0.6
# 2     a3 0.8333333 0.5555556 0.4
```

#### Solution 5

A [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) solution based on `gather` and `spread`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -sample) %>%
  group_by(Column) %>%
  mutate(Value = Value/sum(Value)) %>%
  spread(Column, Value)
dat2
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   sample     a     b     c
# * <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a2     0.167 0.444 0.600
# 2 a3     0.833 0.556 0.400
```

#### Performance Evaluation

I am curious about which method has the best performance. So I conduct the following performance evaluation using the [microbenchmark](/questions/tagged/microbenchmark) package with a data frame having the same column names as OP's example but with 1000000 rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(100)

dat <- data_frame(sample = paste0("a", 1:1000000),
                  a = rpois(1000000, lambda = 3),
                  b = rpois(1000000, lambda = 3),
                  c = rpois(1000000, lambda = 3))

# Convert the data frame to a data.table for later perofrmance evaluation
dat_dt <- as.data.table(dat)    

head(dat)
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   sample     a     b     c
#   <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
# 1 a1         2     5     2
# 2 a2         2     5     5
# 3 a3         3     2     4
# 4 a4         1     2     2
# 5 a5         3     3     1
# 6 a6         3     6     1
```

In addition to all the methods I proposed, I also interested two other methods proposed by others: the `prop.table` method proposed by Henrik in the comments, and the `apply` method by [Spacedman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48140340/7669809). I called all my solutions with `m1_1, m1_2, m2_1, ... to m5`. If there are two methods in one solution, I used `_` to separate them. I also called the `prop.table` method as `m6` and the `apply` method as `m7`. Notice that I modified `m6` to have an output as a data frame so that all the methods can have data frame, tibble, or data.table output.

Here is the code I used to assess the performance.

```
per <- microbenchmark(m1_1 = {dat2 <- dat %>% mutate_at(vars(-sample), funs(./sum(.)))},
                      m1_2 = {dat2 <- dat %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(./sum(.)))},
                      m2_1 = {dat2 <- dat %>%
                        map_at(c("a", "b", "c"), ~./sum(.)) %>% 
                        as_data_frame()
                      },
                      m2_2 = {dat2 <- dat %>%
                        map_if(is.numeric, ~./sum(.)) %>%
                        as_data_frame()},
                      m3 = {dat_dt2 <- copy(dat_dt)
                            dat_dt2[, c("a", "b", "c") := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/sum(x)), 
                                      .SDcols = c("a", "b", "c")]},
                      m4_1 = {dat2 <- dat
                              dat2[, -1] <- lapply(dat2[, -1], function(x) x/sum(x))},
                      m4_2 = {dat2 <- dat
                              dat2[] <- lapply(dat2[], function(x){
                        if (is.numeric(x)){
                          return(x/sum(x))
                        } else{
                          return(x)
                        }
                      })},
                      m5 = {dat2 <- dat %>%
                        gather(Column, Value, -sample) %>%
                        group_by(Column) %>%
                        mutate(Value = Value/sum(Value)) %>%
                        spread(Column, Value)},
                      m6 = {dat2 <- dat
                            dat2[-1] <- prop.table(as.matrix(dat2[-1]), margin = 2)},
                      m7 = {dat2 <- dat
                            dat2[, -1] = apply(dat2[, -1], 2, function(x) {x/sum(x)})}
                      )
print(per)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr         min          lq       mean      median          uq        max neval
# m1_1   23.335600   24.326445   28.71934   25.134798   27.465017   75.06974   100
# m1_2   20.373093   21.202780   29.73477   21.967439   24.897305  216.27853   100
# m2_1    9.452987    9.817967   17.83030   10.052634   11.056073  175.00184   100
# m2_2   10.009197   10.342819   16.43832   10.679270   11.846692  163.62731   100
#   m3   16.195868   17.154327   34.40433   18.975886   46.521868  190.50681   100
# m4_1    8.100504    8.342882   12.66035    8.778545    9.348634  181.45273   100
# m4_2    8.130833    8.499926   15.84080    8.766979    9.732891  172.79242   100
#   m5 5373.395308 5652.938528 5791.73180 5737.383894 5825.141584 6660.35354   100
#   m6  117.038355  150.688502  191.43501  166.665125  218.837502  325.58701   100
#   m7  119.680606  155.743991  199.59313  174.007653  215.295395  357.02775   100


library(ggplot2)
autoplot(per)
```

[image]

The result shows that methods based on `lapply` (`m4_1` and `m4_2`) are the fastest, while the `tidyr` approach (`m5`) is the slowest, indicating that when row numbers are large it is not a good idea to use the `gather` and `spread` method.

#### DATA

```
dat <- read.table(text = "sample   a   b   c
a2      1    4    6
                  a3      5    5    4",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can this answer be updated to use new `dplyr` functionality, notably `across()`?

Comment: FYI - the dplyr operation ```funs()``` is now deprecated so Solution 1 no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in `dplyr` as well.

```
sample <- c("a2", "a3")
a <- c(1, 5)
b <- c(4, 5)
c <- c(6, 4)
dat <- data.frame(sample, a, b, c)
dat

library(dplyr)

dat %>%
    mutate(
        a.PCT = round(a/sum(a), 3),
        b.PCT = round(b/sum(b), 3),
        c.PCT = round(c/sum(c), 3))

  sample a b c a.PCT b.PCT c.PCT
1     a2 1 4 6 0.167 0.444   0.6
2     a3 5 5 4 0.833 0.556   0.4
```

Answer (score -1):

try apply:

```
mat <- matrix(1:6, ncol=3)
apply(mat,2, function(x) x / sum(x))
```

okay, if you have not numeric values in you columns you can force them to be numeric:

```
df <- data.frame( a=c('a', 'b'), b=c(3,4), d=c(1,6))
apply(df,2, function(x) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  x / sum(x)
})
```

Comment: Need to show how to get from the data frame to a matrix and back to a dataframe again.

Comment: The sum will fail because the first column is text in the example.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the transpose of the matrix and then transpose again:

```
t(t(as.matrix(df))/colSums(df))
```