# Dividing all integers of a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to divide all integers in a column with another integer. I have a database with a column that has integers that go above 1*10^20. Because of this my plots are way to big. I need to normalize the data to have a better understanding what is going on. For example, the data that I have:

```
   [x][Day] [Amount]
[1] 1   1   23440100
[2] 2   2   41231020
[3] 3   3   32012010
```

I am using a data.frame for my own data, so here you have the data frame for the data above

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
day <- c(1,2,3)
Amount <- c(23440100, 41231020, 32012010)
my.data <- data.frame(x, day, Amount)
```

I tried using another answer, provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447801/dividing-columns-by-colsums-in-r), but that doesn't seem to work. 
The code that I tried:

```
test <- my.data[, 3]/1000
```

Hope someone can help me out! Cheers, Chester

Comment: `my.data$my_column / my_integer` should work perhaps? You probably just need to assign the values back `<-`?

Comment: The only issue with `test <- my.data[, 3]/1000` is that you put the result in a new variable, `test`. If you want the result to go in `my.data[, 3]`, you need `my.data[, 3] <- my.data[, 3]/1000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this?

```
my.data$Amount <- my.data$Amount/1000
```

such that

```
> my.data
  x day   Amount
1 1   1 23440.10
2 2   2 41231.02
3 3   3 32012.01
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, seems like its more simple than I thought! Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

#### Use mutate from dplyr

Since you're using a `data.frame`, you can use this simple code:

```
library(dplyr)
mutated.data <- my.data %>% 
  mutate(Amount = as.integer(Amount / 1000))

> mutated.data
  x day   Amount
1 1   1 23440.10
2 2   2 41231.02
3 3   3 32012.01
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: After installing the library, and applying the code, it works. However, now I get float values and I tried to keep my integers. Thanks a lot for the answer @Louis!

Comment: You're welcome @Chester. Even with the accepted answer, you'll get `float` values. If you want to have `integer` values, use this updated code. Hope this helps.